# Best practice to implement HTTP API service with Jetpack Compose + Retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, android-jetpack-compose, viewmodel

**Scenario:**

This app allows the user to scan barcodes in the supermarket, and add the items to their virtual cart. The virtual cart should show an image, name and price. This data is sourced from an HTTP API.

**Prerequisites:**

I have a simple `Product` object, which also tracks the quantity:

```kotlin
class Product(
    val barcode: String,
    val name: String,
    val price: Double,
    val category: String,
    val image: Image?,
    initialQuantity: Int = 1
) {
    var quantity by mutableStateOf(initialQuantity)
}
```

Then, I have a viewModel of my cart, which contains a list of Products:

```kotlin
class CartViewModel: ViewModel() {
    // List of my Products in the cart.
    private val _cart: MutableList<Product> = mutableStateListOf<Product>()

    // Getter for the cart
    val cart: List<Product>
        get() = _cart

    /**
     * Removes a product from the cart. Quantities are ignored, so the product is always removed completely.
     */
    fun remove(product: Product) {
        println("Removing product: ${product.name} from cart")
        _cart.remove(product)
    }

    /**
     * Adds a product to the cart. If the product is already in the cart, the quantity is increased.
     */
    fun add(product: Product) {
        val existingProduct = _cart.find { it.barcode == product.barcode }
        if (existingProduct != null) {
            existingProduct.quantity += product.quantity
            println("Increased quantity of product: ${product.name} to ${existingProduct.quantity}")
        } else {
            _cart.add(product)
            println("Added product: ${product.name} to cart")
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I want to connect this viewModel to an API.

**Problem:**

The user scans the barcode '1', now the item is added to the list. Now I'd like to get the image and price from the HTTP API. I read this [guide from Android about data fetching](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-getting-data-internet#5), however, it does not seem to be compatible with the idea of a simple object *in a list*. What is the proper way to implement this?

I tried a different approach using a Service and Repository as described in the documentation, however, this does not work as all, the the CartViewModel needs the productRepository in the constructor, which does not work in Jetpack Compose?

```kotlin
interface ProductService {
    @GET("/product?barcode={barcode}")
    suspend fun getProduct(@Path("barcode") barcode: String): Product
}


class ProductRepository constructor(
    private  val productService: ProductService
) {
    suspend fun getProduct(barcode: String): Product {
        return productService.getProduct(barcode)
    }
}

/**
 * Our viewmodel for representing the cart
 */
class CartViewModel constructor(
    productRepository: ProductRepository
): ViewModel() {
    private val _cart: MutableList<Product> = mutableListOf<Product>()
    val cart: List<Product>
        get() = _cart

    fun add(product: Product) {
        _cart.add(product)
    }

    fun remove(product: Product) {
        _cart.remove(product)
    }


    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _cart.add(productRepository.getProduct("1"))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: At minimum I would wrap the return type of getProduct in ProductService with a Retrofit Response so that you can at least have some form of successful response verification.

Comment: @NathanMeade Thank you for taking the time to read through the question :) I ended up using ktor because it's easier to use in my use case.